# Automatic Btrfs snapshotting as standard user

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

Btrfs allows creating subvolumes and taking snapshots as a standard user. However, the tools I have found for automatically creating and managing snapshots at regular intervals (Snapper and Timeshift) seem to be geared toward keeping snapshots of `/` and expect root privileges to run.

Is there a tool I can run regularly as a normal user while logged in (e.g., via a systemd user timer) that will automatically take snapshots and clean up old ones, keeping a configured number of hourly/daily/weekly snapshots?

Answer (score -1):

The btrfs command should suffice ... for example:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot [-r] $MOUNTDIR/livevolume SOMEWHERE/newsnapname
```

**man btrfs-subvolume** for full documentation

Comment: This is obvious, and not what OP asks for.